# Does getting to Sans quickly on the evacuation route change his dialogue?

Tags: tsunderswap

In [Shayy's Evaculation Route playthrough](https://youtu.be/2HDN1SdDaSM?t=2641) of the Undertale fangame [TS!Underswap](https://gamejolt.com/games/tsunderswap/160094), when they got to Sans near the end of Starlight Isles, he said the following:

> Then, there's the amount of time it took you to get here. I can think of countless evildoers that broke your record. **If you got here just 13 minutes earlier, well, perhaps...** Maybe next time, eh?

Someone in chat mentioned that when they played they got "4 minutes earlier", implying the dialogue changes depending on how fast you play. Does Sans say something different if you get to him early enough?

[image: Sans telling Shayy they should have gotten there 13 minutes earlier]

Comment: Is this an Undertale mod?

Comment: @pinckerman https://tsunderswapofficial.fandom.com/wiki/TS!Underswap

Comment: @pinckerman It's a fangame. I've edited the question to link the game download page.